# Django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL failing when redirecting to the users profile

Tags: django, redirect, registration, profile

I'm using django-registration-redux and have most of it working.  I'm trying to redirect to the user profile after login.  Currently the URL for user profile is:

```
url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

...and the view for the profile is:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not request.user == user:
        return render(request, 'no.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
```

I've added `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'` to settings.py but am getting the error:

```
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(\\w+)/$']
```

I've gone around this so many times I'm totally confused.  I could simply set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'` and be done with it, but then I wouldn't have gotten past this error.  Do I need to create a different view for this?

**EDIT:**

If I set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to `'home'` or `'products'` or any other URL it works - just not for `'profile'`.  Here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^designers/', views.DesignersView.as_view(), name='designers'),
    url(r'^subscribe/$', views.subscribe, name='subscribe'),
    url(r'^products/$', views.products, name = 'products'),
    url(r'^product/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'post_url/', views.post_product, name='post_product'),
    url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    url(r'^like_product/$', views.like_product, name='like_product' ),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='product-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'),
]
```

I'm still searching - just not finding a solution, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way to do this.  I created a login view in my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class LoginView(LoginView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[self.request.user.username])
```

Also added this to my urls.py to reflect the new view:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Removed `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` from settings.py and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex url isn't correct. Change:

```
url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

To

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

Comment: Exact same issue unfortunately.  In the template on a button I've used `{% url 'profile' user.username %}` which works so the url.py pattern works.